# Using launchd to update MacPorts

Tags: macos, launchd, macports

I want to use launchd to update my MacPorts tree periodically (i.e. `port selfupdate`.

I have created `/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.selfupdate.plist`:

```
$ ls -l /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.selfupdate.plist
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  669  8 Nov 12:49 /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.selfupdate.plist
```

It has the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>Label</key>
<string>org.macports.selfupdate</string>
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>/opt/local/bin/port</string>
    <string>selfupdate</string>
</array>
<key>StandardOutPath</key>
<string>/var/log/org.macports.selfupdate.log</string>
<key>StandardErrorPath</key>
<string>/var/log/org.macports.selfupdate.err</string>
<key>RunAtLoad</key>
<true/>
<key>StartInterval</key>
<integer>604800</integer><!-- 1 week -->
</dict>
</plist>
```

I've loaded it and verified that it's loaded:

```
$ launchctl list | grep macports
-   78  org.macports.selfupdate
```

But it doesn't look like it actually run.

```
$ port info wireshark
Warning: port definitions are more than two weeks old, consider updating them by running 'port selfupdate'.
wireshark @1.12.8_3 (net)
...
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You probably put the plist in ~/Library/LaunchAgents/. Since /opt/local is owned by root:wheel (that's at least the default), you don't have the proper permissions to write to certain necessary folders (e.g. /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/tmp). The log files (i.e. /var/log/org.macports.selfupdate.log/err) neither can be created, because only root can write to /var/log/.

So run the selfupdate service as launch daemon:

- Remove the launch agent from the launchd database:

  ```
  launchctl remove org.macports.selfupdate
  ```
- Move the plist to /Library/LaunchDaemons/:

  ```
  sudo mv ~/Library/LaunchAgents/org.macports.selfupdate.plist /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.selfupdate.plist
  ```
- Modify owner and permissions:

  ```
  sudo chown root:wheel /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.selfupdate.plist
  sudo chmod 644 /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.selfupdate.plist
  ```
- Load the daemon:

  ```
  sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.selfupdate.plist
  ```

Such launch daemon is run with root permissions and can update MacPorts data as well as write to /var/log/.

Comment: It was actually in `/Library/LaunchDaemons`.  Isn't that where it should be?  In the meantime I'll check my permissions.

Comment: @StephenRasku Did you launch the daemon initially with `sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.selfupdate.plist`? What does the selfupdate error log/selfupdate normal log reveal?

Comment: I did launch it that way.  I didn't see any logs when I did it.  I just re-did it and added diagnostics and it looks like `rsync` is not connecting to the proxy for some reason.

Comment: I just ran a `port install` command from the command line and that failed too.  I didn't have that problem before.  I'll take a look at it in the morning.

Comment: @StephenRasku The file /var/log/org.macports.selfupdate.log should at least contain **some** details. I have tested this in a VM (first in ~/Lib/LaunchAgents/, then as a launch daemon in /Lib/LaunchD.../. The first attempt failed of course - the second wrote some lines (i.e port's version etc)

Comment: It does have some details.  It's complaining about the proxy right now.  I've recently been messing with my network configuration so that could be affecting it.  I think this is probably an additional problem not the original problem.
When I ran it the first time it didn't create the log files but when I went back to it they were there, timestamped about 4.5 hours after I loaded the job.

Comment: It turns out it was the only problem.  I had a guest network in a VM that was interfering with the proxy setup.  Thanks for your help.